# WPF using IValueConverter and referencing class in app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a WPF app that contains a datagrid. I am trying to use a custom value converter to decide the font colour of a cell.

I have created the class below.

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{    
    public class AboveMeanToBoolConverter : IValueConverter
    {
         public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
            double dValue = System.Convert.ToDouble(value);
            double dParameter = System.Convert.ToDouble(parameter);

            return (dValue > dParameter);  
         }

         public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
         {
            return null;
         }
}
```

In my MainWindow xaml I have the following

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:AboveMeanToBoolConverter x:Key="meanToBool"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

**First issue:**

After typing local: the intellisense shows my class AboveMeanToBoolConverter. However the line is highlighted saying "The name AboveMeanToBoolConverter does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"

**Second Issue**

I have all the styling for my app and datagrid in app.xaml.

Below is a snippet of the xaml in my app.xaml in the section where I'm styling the DataGridRow.The Binding line is highlighted and tells me "The resource "meanToBool" could not be resolved." So how do I reference my converter in my app.xaml? Also my setter is referring to a border (copy & paste from something that is working - how to change this so the font changes colour and not the background of the cell?

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MeanPost, Converter={StaticResource meanToBool}, ConverterParameter=0}" Value="0">
                            <Setter TargetName="DGR_Border" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource brushRowSend}"/>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

**Update**

To answer a comment below. Below is where I have local defined.

In my MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MyNameSpace.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"     
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    MinHeight="800" MinWidth="1000"
    Height="800" Width="1200" 
    Background="LightSteelBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
```

Comment: I know it might be stupid of me to ask that, but since you didn't mention it: where is your definition for the `local` tag? You should have on your `Window`'s attributes something like `xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNameSpace` right? If so: Is the converter in a different assembly?

Comment: Not stupid to ask at all. I've added an update to my post. There you can see where I have defined my local tag

Comment: As I read on the answer, looks like it runs properly. The XAML editor can be a pain sometimes with references (which I fixed by.... using Resharper. Not free though). For your second issue, your `DataTrigger` specifically changes a background. Is the `ControlTemplate` for a `DataGridRow` or a `DataGridCell` ?

Comment: The ControlTemplate is for a DataGridRow. Yes it builds however in app.xaml the Binding line is still highlighted saying "the resource meanToBool could not be resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your first issue looks just Visual Studio XAML editor-related. It sometimes can be a pain for not recognizing references.
I personally fixed this by... using ReSharper!

As for your second issue, you are explicitly styling a `Background` property. If you want to change the text color in a row, you can create a `RowStyle` for your `DataGrid`:

```
                        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MeanPost, Converter={StaticResource meanToBool}, ConverterParameter=0}" Value="0">
                                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource brushRowSend}"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. When I run the app I see in the error list The resource MeanToBool could not be resolved. It is also saying my converter class does not exist in the namespace 'clr-namespace:MyNameSpace'

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in yuor converter, does it go through? If a resource is actually not resolved, the code should throw a XamlParseException and prevent you from running it If you can run it fine, you should have no problem with that

Comment: Its not loading anymore. After the Binding{} I changed the Value=0 to Value="True". I am getting XamlParseException occurred. "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Comment: {"'Provide value on 'System.Windows.Markup.StaticResourceHolder' threw an exception.' Line number '292' and line position '42'."} So my converter class is not getting hit but the app is not loading anymore

Answer (score 0):

Have you build your solution?

Whether its building correctly??

I see a closing brace missing in your converter code .

This is not the answer. As i cant comment , i am adding it as answer.

Comment: Yes it builds fine. The datagrid shows all of the data correctly. However the cells where I would like the font to be a different colour based on the value of the cell is not working. For example if the property MeanPost is say less than 0 it should be red. This is not happening

Comment: So your 1st issue is it resolved now? Can you provide your xaml code to check at my end?